# Copy DataRow from One SQL Table to another Identical SQL Table C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have two identical SQL tables (one is work table and the other is history table). I want to be able to write a record from the work table to the history table whenever a user selects a record to be deleted. The two tables are a clone of each other just to save deleted records to a history file.

Both tables contain an Identity Column (first column) and an image datatype column.

What i want to know is what is the best way to do this. Here is what I have, but I keep getting an error saying:

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'."

```
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM EDI10000 WHERE File_Id = " + fid;
    DataTable dt1 = Vit.GetDataRecords(sql);
    if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {                               
            DataRow dr = dt1.Rows[0];

            int fileId   = int.Parse(fid);
            string tpID  = Vit.GetFieldValue(dr, "Tp_Id");
            string fName = Vit.GetFieldValue(dr, "File_Name");
            int fileSz   = int.Parse(Vit.GetFieldValue(dr, "File_Size"));
            string conType = Vit.GetFieldValue(dr, "Content_Type");

            object obj = Vit.GetFieldValue(dr, "File_Data");
            Byte[] byteData = (Byte[])obj;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteData);

            object[] Insert = new object[] { fileId, tpID, fName, fileSz, ms, conType };
            string sql2 = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO EDI10500 VALUES ({0}, '{1}', '{2}', {3}, '{4}', '{5}')", Insert);
            Vit.UpdateDB(sql2);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I would create a trigger for this and allow SQL Server to handle this for you.

Comment: @websch01ar I'm not sure how to do this. Never used triggers before. I'll try and look it up.

Comment: Looks like your `File_Data` is an nvarchar(max) ? if it is it can go in a simple string. And if you can exexute sql directly, a insert into ...select  will work in this case.

Comment: @rene no my File_Data field is an "Image" field.

Comment: does your UpdateDb method only accept a sql string? You can't give sql parameters with it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ROUGH example of a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_SourceTableName_Audit] ON [dbo].[SourceTableName] FOR DELETE AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO AuditTable (cols)
        Select * from deleted
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- In this case, I just want to eat the error.
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Do I add the trigger to the destination table or the source table? Also, what do you mean by "AuditTable"? Is that my destination table?

Comment: The trigger goes on the source table and it inserts a record of the deleted row into the destination table.

Comment: I typically name my "shadow" table something like AuditTable.  I should have used something like DestTable for readability.